# Is this an adjective clause

Tags: adjectives, relative-clauses

This is a sentence from a book.

> I knew an executive with a large public relations company who won a major account with a redevelopment agency tasked with the project of securing federal dollars to help New Orleans recover after Hurrican Katrina.

"a redevelopment agency tasked with the project of.... after  Katrina."

"which was " should be placed between "agency" and tasked" , making it an adjective clause, but is omitted to make it concise, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that the idea of "which was" is understood to be between "agency" and "tasked". It doesn't need to be written in explicitly because in the construction "*noun*-*participle*", it is implied.

Your use of "should" *might* imply that "which was" was mistakenly left out of the sentence. So please note that the long complicated sentence *is* correct as it appears in the book.